# time javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem: on a customer's homepage the navibar is loaded by javascript, but I need to change some URL's on it. If I just start my script on $(document).ready() it runs before the customers script and has no effect. I only can use setTimeout for my function to wait until the other script is ready, but it's not good or safe at all. I can't change anything on the website, only add a javascript - is there a way to time it after the other one?

Comment: What is the customer's script?

Comment: You can use a deferred done call using jQuery.

Comment: @MarcusRecck What deferred object would he apply the done method to?

Comment: Well he wants to time it so one calls after the other, at least that's what I've gotten from his text. Once the first one calls, he can resolve the deferred object and then call the done method to run the second one.

Comment: The problem is there is no way to resolve the deferred object, it would have to be resolved by customer's script which he has no access to. I don't think there is a way to do it other than using a setTimeout solution in this case.

Comment: It would sure help if there were some kind of example code or page to visit to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use repeated setTimeout, in order to check if menu is accessible.

```
function check_menu(){
    if(document.getElementById('my_menu')==null){
        setTimeout('check_menu()',500);
    } else {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @iambriansreed Why would `setInterval` vs `setTimeout` warrant a downvote? I would actually suggest `setTimeout` over `setInterval` due to having more control over `setTimeout`. The only change I would suggest is using `check_menu` instead of `"check_menu()"`

Comment: setTimeout is used here because we want to call the method only 1 time, it's easier to stop when we want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have information about the menu like the id or class, use the `onLoad()` jQuery method on the element.  For example if the code is loading asynchronously, and you add the onload to one of the last elements it should fire after the content has finished.

```
$.post('AsyncCodeLoad.php', function(data) {
    $('#lastElementToLoad').onLoad(RunMyFunction);
});
```

Or if you have no chance to insert your code into the async loading just add to the bottom of the `</body>`:

```
    $('#lastElementToLoad').onLoad(RunMyFunction);
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add your script at the bottom of the `<body />` tag to ensure it does not run until all other scripts have run.  This will only work however if your customer is loading the nav links synchronously.

If the nav is being loaded asynchronously, use JS's `setInterval` to repeatedly check the contents of the nav for links.  When you determine the links have been added, cancel your interval check and call your script's logic entry point.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xSzjA/

JavaScript

```
var
menu_fix = function(){
    var menu = $('#menu');
    if(menu.length == 0) return;
    clearInterval(menu_fix_int);
    $('a', menu).text('Google Search').attr('href','http://google.com');        
},
menu_fix_int = setInterval(menu_fix, 100);
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu"><a href="http://bing.com">Bing Search</a></div>​
```